# Overscan issue on a CRT TV Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: nvidia, tv

I built a HTPC using an 8400gs S-Video port to display on my old RCA TV in my room. The top and side bar cannot be seen. Switching resolutions doesn't help either.

I'm running Nvidia driver 304

Comment: It's not very descriptive but ask me anything and I will describe it to the best of my ability

Comment: Actually, it's a driver problem. nVidia used to have an option to compensate for overscan but they no longer seem to be in the driver. Maybe you could generate an xorg.conf file and set your screen size smaller than your display size. Theoretically that would work

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to set that up?

Comment: I can't write the xorg.conf file for you because I don't know your sytem well enough (and I don't have nVidia cards anymore) but I'll give it a try in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe setting the screen size in xorg.conf smaller than the display size would help, i don't know if it works but it may be worth a try. First copy your /etc/X11/xorg.conf to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup so in case it doesn't work you can copy it back and all will be as it was.

then from terminal: gksu gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Since I don't know the layout of your xorg.conf I can only give you an example. I persume your TV runs in 800x600 resolution. I also don't have any nVidia card to test here so I don't know if it will support this option. The option that could do the trick is the line **Virtual {width} {height}**. The rest of the code here is just an indication to show where this line should be placed **Don't blindly copy any of this** but use it as a guidance.

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Virtual    640 480
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```